# where is messageSelector applied in message-driven beans?

Tags: java, ejb, jms, message-driven-bean

When is the `messageSelector` logic inside `@MessageDriven` evaluated?

Is it applied in the message broker itself?

In the JMS client?

Or in the bean's proxy wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

Most JMS providers I know about apply the message selection server side for efficiency reasons, but they could apply it client side. In all cases I'm aware of the logic is implemented behind the jms implementation.